# Lambda path parameters are embedded inside path dictionary

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

I have some python AWS lambdas which are deployed using serverless framework and I was able to retrieve the path variables using:

`event.get("variable")`

I am not sure what has changed but now I need to retrieve these path parameters using:

`event.get("path").get("variable")`

I am using lambda integration and my serverless configuration has not changed and looks like:

```
events:
      - http:
          operationId: delete
          path: "${self:custom.prefix}/{id}"
          method: delete
          integration: lambda
          request:         
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
```

I want to retrieve the `id` variable using `event.get("id")`, what do I need to do to remap the path parameters to be retrievable straight from the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I was hallucinating but it doesnt seem as if what I was originally doing can ever work...

This is a solution although it is ugly, but posting here might help someone to understand what it is that I am trying to achieve, which is to get the path and request body into the event with nothing else:

```
request:
  template:                
    application/json: >
      {                    
        "id": "$input.params('id')",
         "name": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$.name')).replaceAll('\\"','')"              
      }
    parameters:
      paths:
        id: true
```

It is not pretty and if there is a more simplistic way to do this then I would appreciate knowing the answer!